# Asking questions: “que” vs. “quel”

Tags: pronoms, adjectifs, interrogative

Are "que" and "quel" considered the same? Can I use them to ask "what" questions, or there are situations one is suitable and the other is not?

Comment: http://www.learnfrenchathome.com/grammaire_que_quoi_quel,.htm

Comment: No: as a question word, *que* is *what* and *quel* is *which*. What lead you to think that they might be interchangeable?

Comment: @Gilles: *What* can also be used as an adjective in English. I think that's where the confusion from the OP comes from.

Answer (score 7):

**Quel** means “which”, but in some cases, you can also translate it as “what”.

For example:

> Quel est ton animal préféré ?

means: “What is your favorite animal?”.

On this question you have to answer **which** animal you like most.
(Yeah, I know, it can also be “what your favorite animal is”, but you can say “which” here!)

---

**Que** is most used for asking questions like: “What do you eat?”

Example:

> Que manges-tu ?

is translated as: “What are you eating?”

What you have to answer is **what** you are eating.

---

**Note:**
*Que* can only be used in the following forms of questions:

- “est-ce que” (***Qu'**est-ce que vous dites?*)
- inversion (***Que** dites-vous*?)

and **not** in questions with intonation! Then **que** will be replaced with **quoi**:

> Tu manges **quoi** ?